# Is it possible to convert a .so compiled for Android into an .so for ubuntu without having the source code?

Tags: android, ubuntu, arm, shared-libraries

I've got an library compiled for android, and I would like to use some of its functions on ubuntu.

Is this possible, and if it is, how can I do this?

I don't have the source code.

Comment: What sort of functions are you interested in, in respect to the Android compiled library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot do.... unless you are running Ubuntu and Android on the same platform (same processor architecture at the bare minimum)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no since ARM binaries are different to x86 binaries in terms of instruction sets. And thusly incompatible with each other.

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that there is already Ubuntu for ARM and Android for Intel

Comment: That was generic, then the OP should explicitly state it in their question!